# On Back press method with different layouts

Tags: android, layout, onbackpressed

I have a single activity  which has two buttons on it .each button opens a new layout .now if i will press back my application will close .but i want to return on Mainactivity and if the user presses back again then app is closed and if he does not press and goes to the second layout and press back then app should not get closed. the condition should be if the user is on Mainactivity and he presses back button then the application closes.
    I came up with an idea on onBackPress method if i could set this condition

```
if (k==1 && Its not a Mainactivity(or the user is not inside a Mainactivity)) {//I dont know how to check for that 

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Mainactivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    this.finish();
} else if (k==1 && Its a Mainactivity(or the user is inside a Mainactivity)) { 
  this.finish(); //then i just want to close the application,I dont know this.finish() ,It does not close the app but still it runs in background 
}
```

**If u guys want to see my code here it is a simple example of what i am trying to achieve:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1,button2;              //Creating button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);      //finding button1
           button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2); //finding button2 
           btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

               setContentView(R.layout.btn1);           

            }
        });


 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         setContentView(R.layout.btn2);
      }
  });

  }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: what u mean by (I dont know this.finish() ,It does not close the app but still it runs in background)??

Comment: i want the app to close but it just closes the session .I know that is the default behaviour of Android app.So i take it back.
Do u have a solution for my prob

Comment: finish kills the app (i dont get the point session came to picture) (what make u think app is still alive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onBackPressed()`, just check the value of `k`. If the value of `k` is `1` or `2`, then 
call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` again to show the main `layout` otherwise call `super.onBackPressed()` to close the `MainActivity`.

You need to call method `initializeButtons()` every time after setting `activity_main` layout to get the `reference` of buttons from layout as well as adding `onClick` listeners.

**TRY THIS:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1, button2;

    int k = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeButtons();
    }

    public void initializeButtons() {
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k = 1;
                setContentView(R.layout.btn1);           
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k = 2;
                setContentView(R.layout.btn2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (k == 1 || k == 2) {
            k = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initializeButtons();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As per discussion in `comment` section, If you want to open `Mainctivity` again during `back` press, then override and update `onBackPressed()` as below:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (k == 1 || k == 2) {
            k = 0;

            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Nice Logic!!.. but if click button 1 and it opens a new layout and i press back and instead of pressing back again i go to button2 then it wont open  thr respective layout.Here your logic fails.any idea how could i achieve that.

Comment: It will open layout btn2, as we set it from button2 onclick method....button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                k = 2;
                setContentView(R.layout.btn2);
            }
        });

Comment: bt it is not opening.see my both xml files 
 b1n1.xml
its a blank layout 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>

and other btn2.xml has a textview

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: nothing fancy here i also cant understan i looked through but its not opening. Please help me.

Comment: I did as u said u can try and check it does not work when opening second button without exiting the app

Comment: It worked.Thank u so much! U r super genius.But can u explain why just adding it to a method worked and previously it was not working.

Comment: Because when you set again layout_main, you have to get the reference of buttons again and need to set listener again. Because your layout is just changing. Just to reduce the common code i make an method.

Comment: you have to do this for all other layout if they contains button or others views to get the proper behavior.

Comment: Btw, happy to know that its working. Please mark my answer as right answer and give an upvote if my answer seems useful and helpful to you. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: wht  if i want this 
  public void onBackPressed() {

        if (k == 1 || k == 2) {
            k = 0;
            Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            initializeButtons();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }}
I want to open mainactivty class its crashing

Comment: instead of opening a layout here i want to open a Mainactivity which contains other stuff .but app crashes when i presss back

Comment: Its happening because you are calling method initializeButtons(). Suppose you press button1, so your current layout is btn1. when you press back it will enter condition    if (k == 1 || k == 2)  {} and open new activity and then call  method initializeButtons(). Inside this button when trying to get reference of button 1 and setting its listener it will crash because your current layout is btn1 and this layout does not contain any button with respective ids.

Comment: Just remove line initializeButtons() from your condition. because you are starting another activity.

Comment: I: got it i just forget to cancel my comment Thanks.buddy can u help me with this.......I marked ur answer and voted .Can u help me with this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967714/implementing-imageslider-gridview-with-picasso/43970973#43970973

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of `onBackPressed()` is to close the current `Activity`. In your case there is only one `Activity` i.e `MainActivity` in which you are changing the layout.

As you are changing the whole content anyways, you might as well create a new `Activity` and `setContentView(R.layout.btn1)` there. And in `onClick()` of the buttons start this new activity. You'll get the functionality you require.

Comment: In my case it is different. i have 30  buttons  each open a new layout ,so i dont want to create 30 activity.Thanks for help though!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you should make separate layout for every activity. And when you click on the `btn1`, it will go to another activity.

But in your code you only change the content of the `MainActivity`.

So you should use `Intent` for moving between activities.

Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondAvtitity.class);
```

So the layout will change and when you press `back button`, app will go back to `MainActivity`.

And when you are in `MainActivity` and you press back button, the app will be closed.

For better explanation I have make an example app:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Bro i have single activity and 30 layouts.I dont want to create 30 activities more .

Comment: I know but my way is very easy and needs no code for back button.

Comment: U r not understanding  bro .I have a single activity and multiple layouts.
How can i implement SecondActivity.class if i dont have second activity

Comment: I know what you mean. But there is a constructional problem in your way of coding. And that is : When you press back button, your code just changes the content of view and it does not read and does not re_execute the whole snippet of MainActivity. So in that time there is not any methods for the buttons ; and when you press the back button , your app will be closed. Is there any way to make the MainActivity be executed again from onBackPressed method?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a stack of all the previous layouts that were added. First add an instance variable:

```
Stack<Integer> layoutHistoryStack = new Stack<>();
```

Then, add these two methods:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(layoutHistoryStack.size() == 1) {
            // the first layout that was added is shown. finish()
            layoutHistoryStack.pop();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // pop() the current layout
        layoutHistoryStack.pop();
        // show the prev
        setContentView(layoutHistoryStack.peek(), false);


    }

    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID, boolean addToHistoryStack) {
        if(addToHistoryStack) layoutHistoryStack.add(layoutResID);
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }
```

Then, replace every previous `setContentView(R.id.layout)` calls with `setContentView(R.id.layout, true)` i.e adding to your `layoutHistoryStack`.

Comment: it closes the app when i  press back once from my layout

Comment: from r button layout or root layout?

Comment: from onclick of each button do this setContentView(R.id.button_layout, true)

Comment: i did already Ferdous's method worked.but i want an explaination so that i can mark the answer correct

Comment: his wont work if there are 100s of layouts to be added. Try mine

Answer (score 0):

How about this one. It really works.

I have completed `Ferdous's snippet`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int k = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            k = 1;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            k = 2;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (k == 1 || k == 2) {
        k = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        this.finishAffinity();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please stop adding multiple answers to the question. Instead edit the old once.